# Entity Framework: Short lived context or application context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to make entity framework work properly with my application. The scenario I have is something like the following: Say I have 8000 items, and each item has 100 components. The way it currently works is I eager load the 8000 items and lazy load the components for each item, because eager loading the entire thing would be too slow on application startup.

As far as I understood in order to have lazy loading working, I need to keep the context alive for the whole application lifetime. So I have a single instance of the context that is open on startup and is closed on exit. I also use that to track changes and save changes.

However I've been reading about EF and many people advise against this approach, in favor of opening and closing contexts at each operation. My question is: how would you go about lazy loading properties, tracking changes, and saving changes if I cannot work with the same context?

Furthermore, I am already facing with issues since I use different threads to load data in the background or save in the background (say it's saving, if I edit a tracking property it raises an exception). I fixed some of them by using a FIFO queue (on a specific thread) for operations on the same context, however tracking properties won't respect the queue.

Some help would be greatly appreaciated as to how to use EF properly

Comment: if you are dependant on lazy loading, keep the context open until all data you need is retrieved. If not, replace it with eager loading.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro The problem is that with lazy loading I can't do stuff such as reloading or saving in the background, because if it happens that a property is "requested" while the context is "busy", lazy loading will stop working.

Comment: Your context is basically an implementation of the Unit of Work pattern.  Having one giant context for the whole app will cause a lot of strange behavior (excessive tracking, caching oddities, unclear states when you commit/complete, etc.) that you probably don't want because it's assumed that you are working with a specific UOW and not globally.

Comment: There is Nuget package Tracker Enabled DbContext extend Entity Framework functionality, have a look: https://www.nuget.org/packages/TrackerEnabledDbContext

Comment: the DbContext does not support multiple threads. however, when you implement a unit of work pattern you should have near to no problems with that behavior, since multiple contexts are supported, just not with the same entries tracked.